# Controlling a C daemon from another program

Tags: c, linux, daemon, interprocess

I'm trying to control a C daemon program from another userspace program.

### *- Simple C daemon*

This daemon is simply a C program which daemonize itself and log a message every second through syslog.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void bye();

int main()
{
  printf("Daemon starting ...\n");
  openlog("daemon-test", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);
  signal(SIGTERM, bye);

  if(0 != daemon(0, 0))
  {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't daemonize\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  syslog(LOG_INFO, "Daemon started !\n");

  while(1)
  {
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Daemon alive\n");
    sleep(1);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void bye()
{
  syslog(LOG_INFO, "Daemon killed !\n");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

### *- Launching and killing the daemon from a C test program*

For test purpose I have developped a minimal example. I'm using `popen` to launch the daemon because I want my program to continue its execution.

After 5 seconds, the test program is supposed to kill the daemon.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DAEMON_NAME       "daemon-test"

int main()
{
    FILE* pipe = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Launching '%s' program\n", DAEMON_NAME);
    if(NULL == (pipe = popen(DAEMON_NAME, "re")))
    {
        printf("An error occured launching '%s': %m\n", DAEMON_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Program '%s' launched\n", DAEMON_NAME);

    while(i<5)
    {
        printf("Program alive !\n");
        sleep(1);
        i++;
    }

    if(NULL == (pipe = popen("killall " DAEMON_NAME, "re")))
    {
        printf("An error occured killing '%s' program: %m\n", DAEMON_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Program '%s' killed\n", DAEMON_NAME);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***Test program log:***

```
$ ./popenTest 
Launching 'daemon-test' program
Program 'daemon-test' launched
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program 'daemon-test' killed
```

***Syslog:***

```
Jun 25 13:58:15 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon started !
Jun 25 13:58:15 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:16 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:17 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:18 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:19 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:20 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 13:58:20 PC325 daemon-test[4445]: Daemon killed !
```

So I'm able to launch and kill the daemon from my C program, however I would like to improve the behaviour in some specific cases.

### *- Handling daemon crash*

The daemon may fail at some point, in that case the control program should be notified so it can be relaunched. My problem is to detect that the daemon has been stopped.

I have though about launching a thread waiting for daemon termination by a call to `pclose`, however it won't work as the daemonization has already closed file descriptors and detached the process.

So I'm looking for the best way to have the program notified on daemon exit.

I could poll using linux calls with `exec` family (such as `pgrep daemon-test` or `ps aux | grep daemon-test`) but I think there are more efficient way to achieve that.

### *- Handling test program error*

If the test program is killed or fails before it kills the daemon, at next execution, two instances of the daemon will run at the same time.

***Test program log:***

```
$ ./popenTest 
Launching 'daemon-test' program
Program 'daemon-test' launched
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
^C
$ ./popenTest 
Launching 'daemon-test' program
Program 'daemon-test' launched
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program alive !
Program 'daemon-test' killed
```

***Syslog:***

```
Jun 25 14:17:25 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon started !
Jun 25 14:17:25 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:26 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:27 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:28 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:29 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:29 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon started !
Jun 25 14:17:29 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:30 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:30 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:31 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:31 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:32 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:32 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:33 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:33 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:34 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:34 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon alive
Jun 25 14:17:34 PC325 daemon-test[4543]: Daemon killed !
Jun 25 14:17:34 PC325 daemon-test[4547]: Daemon killed !
```

I want to avoid this situation by checking if there are already daemon instances running. If not I can launch the daemon from control program.

Otherwise if one or several instances of the daemon are running I shall kill them before launching a new one.

This could be achieved by calling `killall daemon-test` but calling this command at each execution doesn't satisfy me because it's useless most of the time.

Moreover I would like to explicitly log the situation at each execution and though I want to know exactly how many instances were running in that case.

Once again this can be resolved easilly using linux command calls, but I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it.

**Does anybody knows how I could implement daemon process control without having to rely on linux command calls ?**

---

***EDIT:*** *June 26th 2018*

I should have precised it from the beginning but my aim is to be able to monitor the daemon process **without** having to modify its code.

So the daemon doesn't write its pid to a file and is always detached from its caller.

Comment: Ever tried the system call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html ?

Comment: `kill()` would be better to kill daemon either if I had its pid or if it was in the same process group than the caller. So it could have been a solution, however the daemonization has detached the daemon from its parent so it's not in the same process group anymore thus I have to get daemon pid.

Comment: That is the reason, why daemons write their pid to /var/run.

Comment: Umm... from the sysadmin side, shouldn't the distribution's init service (upstart, systemd, whatever) take care of starting the daemon and keeping it going?  your other code for starting/stopping, for sure - just like `apache2ctl` .  Again, from the sysadmin side, I'd add a status check to your controller program, and then write systemd config file and package it all up for whatever distribution(s).

Comment: @ivanivan Usually I would use systemd unit file or system V init script, but I want to overcome the use of such an init system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the program via `popen` why not use the good old POSIX `fork` + `exec`? It gives you a bit more flexibility.

Now, to answer you question:

> My problem is to detect that the daemon has been stopped.

To do this you have to listen to `SIGCHLD` signal in your parent/controlling process. This is good enough since you directly invoked the process. But if you called a shell script which then forked your daemon, it would get difficult. This is why most daemons write something called a `pid` file - A file written by the daemon early on with it's PID as the only content in that file. Normally, people have it put it `/tmp/mydaemon.pid` or something like that.

On Linux, your controlling process can read the PID from this file, then every second you can test if `/proc/<pid>/exe` file exists. If not, you know the daemon died. For example, if your child program's PID is 1234, then `/proc/1234/exe` will be a soft link to the actual location of the executable of the child program.

Something like this:

```
FILE *f;
pid_t pid_child;
char proc_path[256];

f = fopen("/tmp/mydaemon.pid", "r");
fscanf(f, "%d", &pid_child);
fclose(f);
sprintf(proc_path, "/proc/%d/exe", pid_child);

while(1) {
    if (access(proc_path, F_OK) == 0) {
        printf("Program alive !\n");
        sleep(1);
    } else {
        printf("Program dead!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

In fact, this is roughly how many init systems are implemented. See rc, systemd, upstart etc. for a better understanding of how they implement this in more details.

Comment: I have tried after reimplementing `popen` with `fork` + `execl` and by returning child pid and this seems to be a great solution as long as the daemon either write its pid to a file or don't daemonize. I would prefer not modifying the daemon's code so I keep this solution in mind in case no other solution better fit my needs

Comment: `start-stop-daemon` combined with your solution allowed me to do it without having to modify the daemon's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a socket server in daemon, then use control client as normal CLI. CLI sends test messages or control commands to daemon, and daemon gives response. Based on response from daemon, CLI can watch the status of daemon and control it.